# DomDocument problems with encoding and spaces

Tags: php, dom, encoding

I'm trying to parse some HTML of a Website. I had some working code but it wasn't very clean so i rewrote it a litte bit to use DomDocument and XPath.

The problem was that special characters (umlauts and some spaces) getting transformed due to some bug or behavior of DomDocument (see: [php DOMDocument - manipulating and encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659164/php-domdocument-manipulating-and-encoding)). Using the hack mentioned in the answer from Thread above i umlauts are coming out clean (guess i need to use the hack :-( ). But the real problem is that some `&nbsp;` whitespaces still getting transformed (into ASCII 194+160).

Any ideas why this is happening i how i can solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Which encoding does your input have? You could convert it to UTF-8, so that you don't have to inject that hacky `<meta>` tag.

Comment: No it actually is UTF-8 but DomDocument requires this hack. If you follow the link in my post you can see that this is a bug. Using this hack i can work with my previous parsing code, and i also get all the umlauts. The only part that changes are those whitespaces my previous code was eliminating using trim($string, '&nbsp;'), they now appear to be ASCII 194+160 as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

$res = str_replace(array(chr(194), chr(160)),'',$res);

Comment: $res = htmlentities($res);