# PHP DOMDocument messing up encoding

Tags: php

I'm using class to load html on one page, get HTML table content. The page is in windows-1250, so I'm using iconv to convert it to utf-8.
All this is done in one class, that I'm calling like this: `$tableHtml = suplUpdater::getTableHtml(someParams,...);`. When I echo that variable directly, everything looks nice. However, I want to parse the table rows with PHP DOMDocument to save them to database. Code looks like this:

```
$tableData = suplUpdater::getTableHtml(1400450400);
//echo($tableData);

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($tableData);

$rows = $document->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$rows->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($rows->item(0));//first row is just a header

$output = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $currentOutput = array();
    foreach ($row->childNodes as $cell) {
        if ($cell->nodeType == 1) {
            $currentOutput[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    $output[] = $currentOutput;
}
```

When I do `var_dump($output);`, I get array, but it has messed up encoding. Where could be the problem? If needed, I can provide source table data.

---

EDIT:
When I copy table html to txt file, encoded in utf-8 and I do `file_get_contents('tableHtml.txt')`, I get the same result.

---

EDIT:
I have uploaded sample data here:http://anagmate.moxo.cz/data.txt

---

EDIT:
Screenshot of echo and var_dump is here:http://anagmate.moxo.cz/supl.png

Comment: Please post a sample from `$tableData`, as much as is relevant.  And also post a sample from `var_dump($output)`

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659164/php-domdocument-manipulating-and-encoding/

Comment: Thank you so much, man, you saved my day. If you could make it into answer so I could accept it, it would be nice.